# Display rows as blank if another cell is empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following 'hospitals' sheet in excel:

```
   A              B             C             D              E          
1 Regions     Region 1      Region 2      Region 3       Region 4
2 Region 1    Hospital 1    Hospital 6    Hospital 11    Hospital 15
3 Region 2    Hospital 2    Hospital 7    Hospital 12    Hospital 16
4 Region 3    Hospital 3    Hospital 8    Hospital 13    Hospital 17
5 Region 4    Hospital 4    Hospital 9    Hospital 14    Hospital 18
6 Region 5    Hospital 5    Hospital 10
7 Region 6
8 Region 7
9 Region 8
```

On my 'report' sheet, I have the following table set up with column headers 'Region' in A6 and 'Hospital' in B6:

```
       A              B            C            D            E
6   Region         Hospital       Dept     Admissions    Discharges
7   Region 1       Hospital 1     A&E      24            12
8                                
9
10
11                 Hospital 2     Opth     45            76
12
13
14
15                 Hospital 3
16
17
18
19                 Hospital 4
20
21
22
23                 Hospital 5
24
```

A7 in the table above is a drop-down menu with the values from A2-A9 from my 'hospitals' sheet. When this is entered, I'd like to return a list of hospitals from that particular region in cells B7, B11, B15, B19, B23 etc of my 'report' sheet.

However, when it gets to the last hospital in the respective column on the 'hospitals' sheet, I would then like the formatting of columns A:E on the report sheet to appear as blank, rather than have zeros or #N/A values in columns C-E of my report sheet. Is this something that can be done in VBA?

To summarise, basically, I need some code for the workbook that will show the following range of cells report!A27:E30 to be empty/blank of all formatting if there is no value in 'hospitals!B7'. i.e. when the formulas in column B of the 'report' sheet stop pulling values from column b of the 'hospitals' sheet, everything below this will appear empty.

I'm not sure this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not required for the task.
For Sheet 'report' the formula in cells:

```
                B7: =IFERROR("Hospital "&(RIGHT($A$7,1)/1-1)*5+1,"")
               B11: =IFERROR("Hospital "&(RIGHT($A$7,1)/1-1)*5+2,"")
               B15: =IFERROR("Hospital "&(RIGHT($A$7,1)/1-1)*5+3,"")
               B19: =IFERROR("Hospital "&(RIGHT($A$7,1)/1-1)*5+4,"")
               B23: =IFERROR(IF(RIGHT($A$7,1)<3,("Hospital "&RIGHT($A$7,1)/1-1)*5+5,""),"")
```

Comment: This just returns a '1' in the cell formula is entered in.

Comment: try now, the formula lacked the "Hospital " string.